# WSL Networking Error code: Wsl/Service/CreateInstance/CreateVm/ConfigureNetworking/HNS/0x80070424

Tags: wsl-2

I encountered an error starting WSL with Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.133.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 x86_64)

**Detais:**

Falha ao configurar a rede (networkingMode Nat). Para desabilitar a rede, defina 'wsl2.networkingMode=None' no C:\Users\usuario\.wslconfig
Error code: Wsl/Service/CreateInstance/CreateVm/ConfigureNetworking/HNS/0x80070424

I've successfully resolved this issue and wanted to share the solution for anyone who might face a similar problem.

**Solution:**

1. remove Optional Features: Hyper-v platform and Hyper-V managment tool
2. reboot
3. start WSL:  terminal: wsl.exe --install --no-distribution
4. reboot

**Source:** https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/10755

If anyone has experienced this error or has additional insights, feel free to share your thoughts!

Answer (score 10):

Found an easier solution from https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/10495:

- Enable "Virtual Machine Platform" on Windows features and restart.

> Select Start, enter Windows features, and select Turn Windows features on or off from the list of results.
> In the Windows Features window that just opened, find Virtual Machine Platform and select it.
> Select OK. You might need to restart your PC.

Comment: Still doesn't work for me after installing VMWare :/

Comment: Thank you so much. This fixed my issue! There was no way I could turn off Hyper-V, because I use that too. WTF is Microsoft thinking just randomly breaking things with every update? I really need to just move to Linux.

Answer (score 1):

A potential workaround is to use bridged mode (if acceptable). It took only few minutes.

Created a new virtual switch using Hyper-V Manager -> Virtual Switch Manager (see below few steps) + make a small change to `.wslconfig`

change: `c:\users\<USER>\.wslconfig` to include 2 more lines:

```
[wsl2]  # omit that if you already have it. 
networkingMode=bridged
vmSwitch=wsl_switch
```

Create New Virtual Switch: Choose the type of virtual switch you need ( 'External') and click on 'Create Virtual Switch'.

Configure the Virtual Switch:
Name your virtual switch (in my case I named it "`wsl_switch`" see above)
If you chose an external switch, select the network adapter (NIC) you want to use.

There will be a prompt warning about network connectivity disruption. Click 'Yes' if you agree to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs when your **Virtual Machine Platform** and **Windows Hypervisor Platform is not enabled.**

To solve this problem, go to **Control Panel > Programs > Programs and Features, then click on Turn Windows features on or off** or you can search for windows features in control panel search bar.

[Control panel search bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGxce.png)

Scroll down and check the check box for **Virtual Machine Platform**  and **Windows Hypervisor Platform** if uncheck previously then click on OK button and reboot your system.

[Turn on Windows feature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWdAa.png)

After rebooting, run your installed WSL distribution, hopefully your problem will be solved :)